# Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, sdk

I use an EC2 instance to run my build for my Android project. I installed a lot of stuff for Android with the command:

> android update sdk --no-ui

then with:

> android update sdk --no-ui --filter xxxxxx

But when the build is failed:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.2/appcompat-v7-21.0.2.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.2/appcompat-v7-21.0.2.jar
     Required by:
         MyApplication:app:unspecified
```

When I tape:

> android list sdk

There are these packages available:

```
Packages available for installation or update: 3
   1- Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3
   2- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3
   3- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 3
```

Have you got some ideas ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you install the Android Repository on that EC2 instance?

Comment: I updated my original question. Yes @CommonsWare I installed it.

Comment: If you think that your edit has anything to do with the Android Repository, you are mistaken.

Comment: Ok, so how can I do that ?

Comment: Since I haven't played with the CLI way of installing SDK components, I do not know. If you pull up the regular SDK Manager GUI, you will see the Android Repository in the "Extras" area. This sets up a local Maven-style repository which is where the Android Support pacakge's artifacts reside.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem this morning. It seems gradle is using neither local library nor extra-google-m2repository. This can be fixed with Travis CI (see [build 251](https://travis-ci.org/ukanth/afwall/builds/45745789) and a later build 255), but I am still unable to do it right with bare gradle or Jenkins. Still trying.